# fnamemodify filename list obtained from vim globpath giving error inside while loop

Tags: vim

I am trying to get the root file name from a `globpath()` in `viml`. 
With satting dir and fnm name previously, I have:

```
  echo dir
  echo fnm
  echo fnamemodify(globpath(dir, fnm), ':r:t')
```

which is giving

```
/Devel/IO_EOS/objs
*.mod
Devel/IO_EOS/objs/constants.mod
Devel/IO_EOS/objs/mpublic.mod
Devel/IO_EOS/objs/mutil
```

i.e. extension is tripped from the last file only (`mutil`, which is also named as `mutil.mod`)

So, I tried to split the files into list and trip the extension and path as:

```
  let files = filter(split(globpath(dir, fnm), '\n'), '!isdirectory(v:val)')
  echo files len(files)
  let c = 1
  while c <= len(files))
    files[c] = fnamemodify(files[c]), ':r:t')
    let c += 1
  endwhile
```

Now, the files are the list of those file, and properly as a list, the while is not working.
The error quoted is:

```
list index out of range: 3 
invalid arguments for function fnamemodify(files[c]), ':r:t')
invalid expression: fnamemodify(files[c]), ':r:t')
```

Kindly help.
NB: the title became bit complex as somehow SO was not happy with shorter title. sorry for that.

Comment: I've only gave the code a quick look, so I don't know if this is helpful: shouldn't `while c <= len(files)` be `c < len(files)` when iterating over the list `files` (lists are 0-indexed)?

Comment: Yeah I'd say that is the problem as well. In vim, as in virtually every programming language in common use, list indices start at zero and go to len-1.

Comment: may I know what the negative voting is for?

Comment: You could have condensed your example more to show the gist of it; maybe you would have detected the problem on your own through this. Also, there are typos (additional unclosed `)`) in there. Don't get too hung up by the downvotes, but try to be more careful next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vimscript (as in most other programming languages), **List indices are 0-based**. You need to start with `0` and use `<` comparison:

```
let c = 0
while c < len(files)
    files[c] = fnamemodify(files[c], ':r:t')
    let c += 1
endwhile
```

However, as you're iterating over and replacing the same list, you can express this in a more *functional programming* style via `map()`:

```
files = map(files, "fnamemodify(v:val, ':r:t')")
```

Comment: I have sloved it with a map(), e.g. `map(globpath(dir, fnm, 0, 1), 'fnamemodify(v:val, ":t:r")')` . and thanks for your comment also. Yes...my natural instinct says list are 1 based, blame my `fortran` background. 
And downvote is sometime really irritating, with people gives not hint why...so the scope of improve is lost...that's why I asked it. 
Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark next to it.